# why is 219 running before the gnome login on my computer?

Tags: gnome, updates

when I restart I get a black screen then a gray screen with a 219 heading and a screen full of entries with ok after some of them and then the gnome login. also after doing a dist upgrade the id in the settings details shows that it has reverted to 14.10 but is still 15.04 i'm confused.

Comment: As of 15.04 Ubuntu has switched to a different system that brings up all the basic services. As AB appropriately mentioned, that's your systemd version. To stop seeing those messages, you should edit your `/etc/default/grub` file, specifically line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Answer (score 0):

`219` is your `systemd` version.

```
% apt-cache policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 219-7ubuntu6
  Candidate: 219-7ubuntu6
  Version table:
 *** 219-7ubuntu6 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     219-7ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

`systemd` is one of the first things which are activated at startup.

> systemd is a system and service manager for Linux. It provides
>   aggressive  parallelization capabilities, uses socket and D-Bus
>   activation for starting  services, offers on-demand starting of
>   daemons, keeps track of processes  using Linux control groups,
>   supports snapshotting and restoring of the system  state, maintains
>   mount and automount points and implements an elaborate  transactional
>   dependency-based service control logic.

This is absolutely normal if the `splash` and/or `quiet` kernel parameters are removed...